# gcp giving it roles iam roles to configure the policiy

Tags: firebase, function, google-cloud-platform

so what every i am doing in the gcp giving it roles iam roles to configure the policies , i am not able to do to my firebase project. i am able to log into it using my terminal with firebase login and then then firebare init is there and i put the function initilaize but it says i don't have permission to do that i need to give it permission so i open the file

/iam-admin/iam?folder=&organizationId=&project=clone-6de06 because this is my firebase project but i dont' have access to it in the gcp so i am not able to change the permission to change the policy or

need to run the role command

> gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ourcafe-mucqxq 
> --member=serviceAccount:service-1044193269753@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com
>
> --role=roles/cloudfunctions.serviceAgent as that says it will take care of  following error: Deployment of your Cloud Function failed:
> Missing necessary permission resourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy for
> service-1044193269753@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com on
> resource projects/ourcafe-mucqxq. Please grant
> service-1044193269753@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com the
> Cloud Functions Service Agent

any help will be appreciated thank for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to log in to [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#sign-in-test-cli) with a proper account?
If you're not sure that your account with proper permission, you can go to Firebase project >> Project settings >> Users and permission to check that your account is on the list with the right permission.

Also, you can see all of the accounts on the IAM of GCP console.